# grabbing child from html table

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

Trying to grab some table data from a website.

Here's a sample of the html that can be found here https://www.madeinalabama.com/warn-list/:

```
<div class="warn-data">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Closing or Layoff</th>
                        <th>Initial Report Date</th>
                        <th>Planned Starting Date</th>
                        <th>Company</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>Planned # Affected Employees</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Closing *       </td>
                                    <td>09/17/2019</td>
                                    <td>11/14/2019</td>
                                    <td>FLOWERS BAKING CO.                                                          </td>
                                    <td>Opelika                                  </td>
                                    <td> 146                                      </td>
                                </tr>


                                <tr>
                                    <td>Closing *       </td>
                                    <td>08/05/2019</td>
                                    <td>10/01/2019</td>
                                    <td>INFORM DIAGNOSTICS                                                          </td>
                                    <td>Daphne                                   </td>
                                    <td> 72                                       </td>
                                </tr>
```

I'm trying to grab the data corresponding to the 6th td for each table row.

I tried this:

```
url = 'https://www.madeinalabama.com/warn-list/'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get(url)

elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[6]").text
```

and elements comes back as this:

```
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8199967d541da323f5d5c72623a5e607", element="7d2f8991-d30b-4bc0-bfa5-4b7e909fb56c")>,
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8199967d541da323f5d5c72623a5e607", element="ba0cd72d-d105-4f8c-842f-6f20b3c2a9de")>,
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8199967d541da323f5d5c72623a5e607", element="1ec14439-0732-4417-ac4f-be118d8d1f85")>,
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8199967d541da323f5d5c72623a5e607", element="d8226534-4fc7-406c-935a-d43d6d777bfb")>]
```

Desired output is a simple df like this:

```
Planned # Affected Employees
146
72
.
.
.
```

Please someone explain how to do this using selenium find_elements_by_xpath. We have ample beautiful_soup explanations.

Comment: If anyone can explain how to use the xpath method in selenium I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html) function:

```
txt = '''<div class="warn-data">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Closing or Layoff</th>
                        <th>Initial Report Date</th>
                        <th>Planned Starting Date</th>
                        <th>Company</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>Planned # Affected Employees</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Closing *       </td>
                                    <td>09/17/2019</td>
                                    <td>11/14/2019</td>
                                    <td>FLOWERS BAKING CO.                                                          </td>
                                    <td>Opelika                                  </td>
                                    <td> 146                                      </td>
                                </tr>


                                <tr>
                                    <td>Closing *       </td>
                                    <td>08/05/2019</td>
                                    <td>10/01/2019</td>
                                    <td>INFORM DIAGNOSTICS                                                          </td>
                                    <td>Daphne                                   </td>
                                    <td> 72                                       </td>
                                </tr>'''


df = pd.read_html(txt)[0]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Closing or Layoff Initial Report Date Planned Starting Date             Company     City  Planned # Affected Employees
0         Closing *          09/17/2019            11/14/2019  FLOWERS BAKING CO.  Opelika                           146
1         Closing *          08/05/2019            10/01/2019  INFORM DIAGNOSTICS   Daphne                            72
```

---

Then:

```
print(df['Planned # Affected Employees'])
```

Prints:

```
0    146
1     72
Name: Planned # Affected Employees, dtype: int64
```

---

EDIT: Solution with BeautifulSoup:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for tr in soup.select('.warn-data tr:has(td)'):
    *_, last_column = tr.select('td')
    all_data.append(last_column.get_text(strip=True))

df = pd.DataFrame({'Planned': all_data})
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Planned
0     146
1      72
```

---

Or:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

all_data = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in soup.select('.warn-data tr > td:nth-child(6)')]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Planned': all_data})
print(df)
```

Comment: Can you show me how to do it using the xpath method?

Comment: @wolf7687 I'm not using `selenium`, but if you want I can show you with `beautifulsoup`.

Comment: Hopefully the xpath method is similar for both. Please show me with bsoup. Thanks.

Comment: @wolf7687 `beautifulsoup` is using own API/CSS selectors. But I think you can use CSS selectors in `selenium` too. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

*You could also do `td:nth-last-child(1)` assuming its the last child*

> *`soup.select('div.warn-data > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-last-child(1)')`*

*Example*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="warn-data">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Closing or Layoff</th>
                        <th>Initial Report Date</th>
                        <th>Planned Starting Date</th>
                        <th>Company</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>Planned # Affected Employees</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Closing *</td>
                        <td>09/17/2019</td>
                        <td>11/14/2019</td>
                        <td>FLOWERS BAKING CO.</td>
                        <td>Opelika</td>
                        <td> 146 </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Closing *</td>
                        <td>08/05/2019</td>
                        <td>10/01/2019</td>
                        <td>INFORM DIAGNOSTICS</td>
                        <td>Daphne</td>
                        <td> 72 </td>
                    </tr>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')
elements = soup.select('div.warn-data > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-last-child(1)')


for index, item in enumerate(elements):
    print(index, item.text)
```